# Can you submit to journals after presenting cases as eposter in conferences?

Tags: journals, self-plagiarism, publishability, poster, medicine

I had a few medical cases that I presented in conferences as an eposter, I sumbitted the case as eposter, It was presented as a slideshow in big screens in the conference
My understanding is that eposters are not considered publications; so can I submit these cases to journals?

Some journals specify as a requirement that the case submitted should not be published before on other journals or electronically. Where do cases presented as eposter stand on this?

Comment: Is the eposter available online?

Comment: yea the eposter is available online in the website of the conference in the eposter section. 
@Wrzlprmft I sumbitted the case as eposter, It was presented as slideshow in big screens in the conference, thats it. not published on journals online or paper.

Answer (score 3):

*Very* few medical journals consider a poster presentation a publication. So vanishingly few that I have never encountered one in my career. Indeed, the primary expectation of the posters I've encountered is "This'll someday be a paper, but these are the preliminary results."

As long as it hasn't been worked into a full paper as part of the conference, there's no reason to worry.

If you're concerned about it, you can include a sentence in your cover letter to the journal something like the following:

"This manuscript is not under consideration at any other journal, however the preliminary results have been presented as an ePoster at the *Conference of Big Deal Science*."

Answer (score 1):

You should check the specific journal's rules about this.

I have worked on the editorial side of a number of journals, and have been happy to accept full research papers based on work presented at conferences. This is assuming that the submitted paper has been "worked up" to full paper length and detail (the results presented at conferences are not typically comprehensive), and that there is not excessive overlap (a conference proceedings publisher may well hold the relevant copyright).

I write this with the caveat that I have experience in physics and related publishing but not in medical publishing. In any case, I imagine that there's enough variation in practice between different journals within your field to make enquiring with the editors a necessary precaution. Good luck!